# Compare two different size of string arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two string arraylists with difference size. I need to compare these two arraylists and take output. But it gave an error as `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6"`  . What are the changes I need to do for that error. My code is,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestCompareArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f"));
    ArrayList<String> arr2=  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("b","d","f"));

            for(int i = 0; i <= arr1.size(); i++){
                if(arr2.contains(arr1.get(i))){
                     System.out.println("yes");
                }
                     else{
                         System.out.println("No");
                     }}
}}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= arr1.size(); i++){
```

With using `<` instead of `<=` like this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++){
```

Because the size of ArrayList start from `0` to `size()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `retain all`, ist fast precise and efficient:

```
 String orig[] = { "a", "b", "b", "c" };
 String act[] = { "x", "b", "b", "y" };
 List origList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(orig));
 List actList = Arrays.asList(act);
 origList.retainAll(actList);
 System.out.println(origList);
```